# Retain multi selection in Altair interactive legend when chart is clicked

Tags: legend, selection, altair, vega-lite

I have created a compound bar chart in Altair with an interactive legend, where bars from one chart and legend elements can both be selected to filter another chart. This works well when only a single legend element is selected. However, when multiple legend elements are selected, selecting a bar alters the legend selection.

See the minimal example below. [In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22fTo.png), the Crookston and Duluth sites have been selected, with the result that the chart of sum of yield by year is filtered to those two sites. However, if I then click on the Manchuria bar in the sum of yield by variety chart, the legend selection changes so that only Duluth is selected, as seen [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMttU.png). (If I instead shift-click on the Manchuria bar, then only Crookston is selected in the legend.) The desired outcome is for both Crookston and Duluth to remain selected in the legend.

Is it possible to prevent the legend's selection from changing when the chart is clicked?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

bar_selection = alt.selection_multi(encodings=["y"])
legend_selection = alt.selection_multi(encodings=["color"], bind="legend")

varieties = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x="sum(yield)",
    y="variety",
    color="site",
    opacity=alt.condition(
        bar_selection, alt.value(1.0), alt.value(0.25)
    ),
).add_selection(bar_selection)

years = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x="sum(yield)",
    y="year:N",
    color="site",
).transform_filter(
    bar_selection
).transform_filter(
    legend_selection
)

(varieties & years).add_selection(legend_selection)
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in VL, lets see https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7602